# Matlab eps text too small when figure is scaled in LaTeX

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, pie-chart, eps

I'm making Pie Charts in Matlab which I import to my LaTeX report. When automatically saving the Pie-Chart as eps files which I have LaTeX displaying and scaled down. The text gets too small.

I've been trying to make the text bigger and/or make the pie relatively smaller. The default size of the pie is too big for my report so I scale it down by 25%.

In Matlab I need to make the pie 25% smaller or text 400% bigger.

**Matlab:**

```
figure(1)
h = pie([100 10]);
    hstr = {'Yes : ';'No : '}; % strings    
    title('Question one')
    hText = findobj(h,'Type','text'); % text object handles
    hPatch = findobj(h,'Type','patch'); % text object handles
    hpercentValues = get(hText,'String'); % percent values    
    hcombinedstrings = strcat(hstr,hpercentValues); % strings and percent values
    hText(1).String = hcombinedstrings(1);
    hText(2).String = hcombinedstrings(2);
    set(hPatch(1), 'FaceColor', 'r');
    set(hPatch(2), 'FaceColor', 'g');
    print -depsc Sp1.eps
```

I've tried

```
hFig = figure(1);
set(hFig, 'Position', [0 0 200 200])
```

to make the figure smaller and

```
set(gca,'FontSize',48)
```

to make the font larger

**LaTeX:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{epstopdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{Figures/Sp1}
    \label{fig:Sp1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: "`I've been trying to make the text bigger and/or make the pie relatively smaller. `": do the above show how you tried to make the text bigger? If not, why not? What did you try? How didn't it work?

Comment: Maybe try using `psfrag` along with `matlabfrag` to let LaTeX handle the text?

Comment: I've updated the question. I've never heard of `psfrag` and `matlabfrag`. Will take a look at that. Thanks